# How to create multi-level sliding menu?

Tags: java, android, slidingmenu, multi-level

i want to create a multi-level sliding menu with some items in android with java.

In this scenario, each level is a column and first column always shown, when user slide menu in right direction another column with another item will be shown, for example if three column exist user can view all column with two slide action(two because first column always shown)... i appreciate for any help or idea... thanks

level 1:

[image: level 1]

level 2:

[image: level 2]

level 3:

[image: level 3]

Comment: Please insert the images directly instead of posting the links

Comment: do you know how may levels you have? 3 ? or you might have more, less?

Comment: @StavroXhardha no , 3 is maximum

Comment: than create 3 recyclerviews and add them to that fragment. on click of the first, set the other visible and so on